# Does table tag disable work in Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html-table, setattribute

I am using the following code, the disable function works perfectly fine for IE but not for Chrome/Firefox.
Can I know why this property does not work in Chrome?
I see that the value for the tag does get set, but it doesn't work.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <table id="gone">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="myFun()">
    <script>
    function myFun() 
    {
    var ab=document.getElementById('gone');
    ab.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to W3c recommendations the following HTML elements can be disable button,input,select,textarea,optgroup,option and fieldset "http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html" So if you want to disable a table then it is not possible because it do not has any disable attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it works on IE either. Your function works correct, but you need to disable the select, not the table.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csv6uy86/5/)

```
 function myFun() 
    {
    var ab=document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    ab[0].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
    }
```

Comment: Does that fiddle solved the problem for Chrome/Mozilla then?

Comment: Yes it does, but I wanted to disable table as a whole :( guess that is not possible

Comment: You cant disable table, as it is read only. Not in IE, not in any browser.

You can, for example, disable an input or a behavior, not a table.

Comment: Have you tried that in IE outside of jsfiddle? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: Yes in Visual Studio also the same thing worked. I am not sure why it is not working for you. My requirement was to disable the table, I see that is not happening in Chrome/FF. So I guess I will disable the drop downs.